# django configuration, mod_rewrite, mod_alias

Tags: django, configuration, mod-rewrite

I've made a django site for a magazine, and it's found in mag.org/django-site.  the old site is still at mag.org/httpdocs (hosted by mediatemple).

I would like it so that a hit to www.mag.org turns up the django site (as is currently the case, configured so in the conf file)  while a hit to archive.mag.org serves the old site from httpdocs, that is, it's served by apache and not mod_python.

Is this possible to do through mod-rewrite, or mod-alias?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need either of those. Just set up your virtualhosts so that archive.* serves from httpdocs and www.* serves via mod_python (although I really, really recommend you serve Django via mod_wsgi).

For example:

```
<VirtualHost "*:80">
    ServerName www.mag.org
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
    PythonOption django.root /mysite
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost "*:80">
    ServerName archive.mag.org
    DocumentRoot "/var/apache2/httpdocs"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You can add the appropriate log lines to the old site as well to determine how long you really need to keep the archive online.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I think this will work at webfaction, but unfortunately I'm stuck with a mediatemple dv server mediatemple, and I don't think virtualhost works the same way.  

directory structure is : 
var/www/vhosts/mag/mysite/
    httpdocs/
    conf
        vhost.conf
    subdomain/archive/
        httpdocs
        conf
            vhost.conf
                                    
maybe I can add [DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/mag/httpdocs"] to /subdomain/archive/conf/vhost.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use mod_rewrite, fe.:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mag.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mag.org/django-site [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^archive.mag.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mag.org/httpdocs [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately the redirecion is visible to the user as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mag.org/httpdocs

was all I needed, sitting all alone in  /var/www/vhosts/mag.org/subdomains/archive/vhost.conf

The virtualhost solution didn't work for mediatemple, because each vhost.conf is already delimited as a virtualhost, configured by plesk.

Thanks for the help everyone.